# Java applet play multiple .wav files

Tags: java, applet

Hello I am trying to create a simple game, and right now I am trying to add a couple songs to play in the background during the game, which can be stopped and skipped as the player wishes. It seems everywhere I look I can't seem to make the example code work. and the only example that does work can only play one file either in a loop or not.

```
public void loadmedia ()
{
    song1 = getAudioClip (getCodeBase (), "song1.au");
    song1.play ();

    song2 = getAudioClip (getCodeBase (), "song2.au");
            song2.play ();
}
```

song1 will play normally but song2 will do nothing, even if I tell song 1 to stop with a button and play song2.

Comment: *"but song2 will do nothing"*  Have you ***ever*** heard `song2` play via an `AudioClip`?  If not, test that it does work with just that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working answer, thanks a lot for all those who tried to help me out, i ended up using Audio Stream and Input stream.

defining my input stream:

```
private AudioStream as;
```

method called to change songs, when the app starts, and when the next song button is pressed

```
public void musicconfig ()
{
    try
    {
        if (mutestate == false)
        {
            AudioPlayer.player.stop (as);
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream (filename [count]);
            as = new AudioStream (in);
            AudioPlayer.player.start (as);
        }
    }

    catch (IOException b)
    {
        b.printStackTrace ();
    }
    count++;

    if (count == 12)
    {
        count = 1;
    }
}
```

setup my song list array when app first runs

```
public void mediaload ()
{
    filename [1] = "song1.wav";
    filename [2] = "song2.wav";
    filename [3] = "song3.wav";
    filename [4] = "song4.wav";
    filename [5] = "song5.wav";
    filename [6] = "song6.wav";
    filename [7] = "song7.wav";
    filename [8] = "song8.wav";
    filename [9] = "song9.wav";
    filename [10] = "song10.wav";
    filename [11] = "song11.wav";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you need change your background song? Or after song 1 finished, song 2 start?
Sorry I can add it as a comment because my reputation < 50
This code for you to choose a couple of songs in a combobox. Give it a try. If it is not suitable for you. Give me the question again :)

Hope you like it!

```
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

public class SoundApplication extends JPanel
                          implements ActionListener,
                                     ItemListener {
SoundList soundList;
String auFile = "spacemusic.au";
String aiffFile = "flute+hrn+mrmba.aif";
String midiFile = "trippygaia1.mid";
String rmfFile = "jungle.rmf";
String wavFile = "bottle-open.wav";
String chosenFile;

AudioClip onceClip, loopClip;
URL codeBase;

JComboBox formats;
JButton playButton, loopButton, stopButton;
JLabel status;

boolean looping = false;

public SoundApplication() {
    String [] fileTypes = {auFile,
                           aiffFile,
                           midiFile,        
                           rmfFile,
                           wavFile};
    formats = new JComboBox(fileTypes);
    formats.setSelectedIndex(0);
    chosenFile = (String)formats.getSelectedItem();
    formats.addItemListener(this);

    playButton = new JButton("Play");
    playButton.addActionListener(this);

    loopButton = new JButton("Loop");
    loopButton.addActionListener(this);

    stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
    stopButton.addActionListener(this);
    stopButton.setEnabled(false);

    status = new JLabel(
                "Click Play or Loop to play the selected sound file.");

    JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
    controlPanel.add(formats);
    controlPanel.add(playButton);
    controlPanel.add(loopButton);
    controlPanel.add(stopButton);           

    JPanel statusPanel = new JPanel();
    statusPanel.add(status);

    add(controlPanel);
    add(statusPanel);

    startLoadingSounds();
}

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
    chosenFile = (String)formats.getSelectedItem();
    soundList.startLoading(chosenFile);
}

void startLoadingSounds() {
    //Start asynchronous sound loading.
    try {
        codeBase = new URL("file:" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    soundList = new SoundList(codeBase);
    soundList.startLoading(auFile);
    soundList.startLoading(aiffFile);
    soundList.startLoading(midiFile);
    soundList.startLoading(rmfFile);
    soundList.startLoading(wavFile);
}

public void stop() {
    onceClip.stop();        //Cut short the one-time sound.
    if (looping) {
        loopClip.stop();    //Stop the sound loop.
    }
}    

public void start() {
    if (looping) {
        loopClip.loop();    //Restart the sound loop.
    }
}    

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    //PLAY BUTTON
    Object source = event.getSource();
    if (source == playButton) {
        //Try to get the AudioClip.
        onceClip = soundList.getClip(chosenFile);
        stopButton.setEnabled(true);
        onceClip.play();     //Play it once.
        status.setText("Playing sound " + chosenFile + ".");
        if (onceClip == null) {
            status.setText("Sound " + chosenFile + " not loaded yet.");
        }
        return;
    }

    //START LOOP BUTTON
    if (source == loopButton) {
        loopClip = soundList.getClip(chosenFile);

        looping = true;
        loopClip.loop();     //Start the sound loop.
        loopButton.setEnabled(false); //Disable start button.
        stopButton.setEnabled(true);
        status.setText("Playing sound " + chosenFile + " continuously.");
        if (loopClip == null) {
            status.setText("Sound " + chosenFile + " not loaded yet.");
        }
        return;
    }

    //STOP LOOP BUTTON
    if (source == stopButton) {
        if (looping) {
            looping = false;
            loopClip.stop();    //Stop the sound loop.
            loopButton.setEnabled(true); //Enable start button.
        } else if (onceClip != null) {
            onceClip.stop();
        }
        stopButton.setEnabled(false);
        status.setText("Stopped playing " + chosenFile + ".");
        return;
    }
}

public static void main(String s[]) {
    WindowListener l = new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}
    };
    JFrame f = new JFrame("SoundApplication");
    f.addWindowListener(l);
    f.getContentPane().add(new SoundApplication());
    f.setSize(new Dimension(400,100));
    f.show();
}
```

}

Comment: No need to apologize, basically I want it to start song 2 when the user presses a button, or when the song 1 is finished. I've found several methods on how to do this, but it seems because my program is an applet it doesn't usually work, and because i'm very new I don't completely understand some of it.

Comment: I have just edit my answer. Check it out. Your problem is not Applet or Application. Don't worry about it, mah friend.

Comment: thanks for the code! unfortunately for me it wouldn't work, but I used some ideas from that and from other examples to put together my own. thanks a lot! I'd vote up but I need more reputation to do that